# Correct monomer for polycondensation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I'd like to formulate the synthesis reaction of this polymer:

[image]

I assume this is a normal polycondensation reaction, and the monomer would then be:

[image]

Is this correct?

Comment: Try bis-phenol A and phosgene or its equivalent.

Comment: Why you didn't check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycarbonate ?

Comment: Yeah, this is totally a polycarbonate, thanks... I guess it was late. However, I would still be interested in knowing whether or not the monomer I wrote down could perform a nucleophilic attack at the carboxyl C atom of a second molecule, form a tetrahedral intermediate and condense off a water molecule. Probably not (otherwise why go for phosgene), but why?

Comment: The monomer you drew is not stable; carbonic acids decarboxylate under standard laboratory temperatures and pressures to the alcohol. It's also very difficult to get phenol derivatives to react with CO2 at the oxygen atom, rather than the ortho carbon atom.